# How to correctly connect reCAPTCHA?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, recaptcha

Got contact form like this ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/13736/)).
Registered captcha. How to implement the correct integration on the client and server?

In the form inserted just a `div`. `Submit` gonna work like this? How to connect `submit` and captcha?

It refers to the POST request:

[image]

How does it send?

There is PHP:

```
<?php

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    $recipient = "mail@mail.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "New contact from $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

Comment: http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-google-recaptcha/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have integrated the google reCaptcha in our website. Here is our implementation.

**Front-end Code:**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaCallBack&amp;render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var recaptcha_sponsorship_signup_form;
var recaptchaCallBack = function() {
    // Render the recaptcha on the element with ID "recaptcha_sponsorship_signup_form"
    recaptcha_sponsorship_signup_form = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha_sponsorship_signup_form', {
        'sitekey' : 'your_recaptcha_website_key',
        'theme' : 'light'
    });
};
</script>

<dt>Prove you’re not a robot</dt>
<dd style="height: 78px;">
<div id="recaptcha_sponsorship_signup_form"></div>                  
</dd>
```

**Server Side Code:**

```
$fileContent = '';
if (isset($_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']) && !empty($_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $fileContent = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=your_recaptcha_secret_key&response=". $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response']);
}

$jsonArray = json_decode($fileContent, true);
if (isset($jsonArray['success']) && $jsonArray['success']==true) {
    // process your logic here
} else {
    echo "Invalid verification code, please try again!";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems it works for me. But there is some questions. Testing on XAMPP. Cheking 'mailoutput'. When I filled the form, but didn't check captcha,  the message didn't come, thats nice, but the form just cleared and no message pop-up for user. So the point, that user didn't get any message, that he missed captcha. And form works without captcha, but didn't send.  How I can fix it?

Comment: if user didn't check captcha, please add http_response_code(403); to else condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library ;

https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/master/examples/example-captcha.php

---

First, register keys for your site at https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

When your app receives a form submission containing the g-recaptcha-response field, you can verify it using:

```
<?php
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp);
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
    // verified!
} else {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
}
```

You can see an end-to-end working example in examples/example-captcha.php